# DR for Docker persistent storage on NFS

Tags: docker, nfs4, docker-swarm

At the moment we have a Docker Swarm setup with DTR, UCP etc using a local NFS server for DTR and persistent storage.

We would like to have a DR setup at a remote data center which has high speed connectivity with primary site. We are planning to extend the existing Docker Swarm cluster by adding a couple more workers and managers at the DR site. Is this the right approach?

Also, what would be the best way to get the Docker persistent storage replicated at the DR site so that the containers can switch over in case the primary site is completely down?